# Regressão Linear Múltipla no R

Tags: r, ggplot2, anova

Olá, estou com dados (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JdgsnJn5VrkL8j1BsfWzqYW9fMGXND6U) de um experimento inteiramente casualizado, em que foi avaliado o **crescimento de um fungo** em resposta a aplicação de diferentes **doses** (0.25, 0.50, 0.75 e 1.00) de diferentes **fungicidas** (4 naturais + 1 químico + controle com água). No total foram 24 tratamentos x 4 repetições cada.

Como não tenho domínio do R, gostaria de saber qual o script adequado para realizar a ANOVA, a regressão e gerar os gráficos já ajustados para cada situação.

Atenciosamente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dados <- read.table('IVCM.txt', header = TRUE)

regLin <- lm(IVCM ~ TRAT * RE, dados)
# o asterisco na fórmula indica que é para calcular também a interação
# você pode usar "+" no lugar se quiser o cálculo sem interação

summary(regLin)  # resumo do modelo

anova(regLin)  # tabela ANOVA

par(mfrow=c(2,2)); plot(regLin)  # gráficos de avaliação
```

Lembre-se de checar os pressupostos do modelo e o ajuste. Nos seus dados de exemplo, os resíduos não seguem distribuição Normal, entre outras coisas. Você pode tentar um modelo linear generalizado: ele é rodado no R usando a função `glm`, que usa a mesma sintaxe de fórmula, mas com o adicional de especificar a função de probabilidade.

Um excelente guia para modelos lineares no R (em inglês) é o capítulo 9 do livro "Ecological Models and Data in R". Ele está disponível em PDF no site do autor: https://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/emdbook/

Comment: Obrigado @Carlos, suas recomendações me ajudaram a solucionar o problema. Atenciosamente!