# Equação da Forma no R- Regressão Múltipla

Tags: r

Preciso resolver uma questão no R e não tenho ideia de como fazer o R me dar equação que ajuste os dados,segue as informações e a foto da questão:

Tenho dados das seguintes tabelas:

```
Idade X1 = (38,46,39,43,32)
Anos de Faculdade X2 = (4,0,5,2,4)
Rendimento em Dólares Y= (81700,73300,89500,79800,69900)
```

Preciso criar uma equação da forma que ajustes esses dados, na forma:

```
y = b0 + b1x1 + b2x2
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amh9k.png

Comment: Quer fazer uma regressão linear, é isso? Eu não editei o título para lhe questionar aqui no comentário.

Comment: Sim,gostaria de fazer uma regressão linear múltipla,porém não sei como fazer para o R me dar a equação que ajuste esses dados.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Regressão Linear Múltipla no R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329648/regress%c3%a3o-linear-m%c3%baltipla-no-r). Veja também [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219446/regress%C3%A3o-m%C3%BAltipla-com-r/219466#219466) questão para ver se ajuda.

Comment: Dei uma olhada no link e acredito que minha dúvida seja diferente. Eu não sei pedir ao R que me dê a equação da Regressão

Comment: O que quer dizer "da forma"? E, o que espera ter como resposta? Tente editar a pergunta. Está pouco clara.

Comment: Eu consegui fazer pelo Excel,mas preciso que seja pelo R. A resposta seria essa: Y = -16739.60122 + 1960.924952 * X1 + 5975,657713 * X2

Comment: É preciso o vetor `Y`, senão não podemos ajustar o modelo. Os coeficientes serão dados por `coef(lm(Y ~ X1 + X2))`.

Comment: Está no [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amh9k.png), @Rui.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Após conseguir os coeficientes,como posso conseguir o modelo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta ajustar um modelo linear com termo independente, a interseção com o eixo dos yy.

```
Y <- c(81700, 73300, 89500, 79800, 69900)
X1 = c(38,46,39,43,32)
X2 = c(4,0,5,2,4)

modelo <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2)
coef(modelo)
#(Intercept)          X1          X2 
# -16739.601    1960.925    5975.658
```

Para responder à pergunta no link, qual o salário médio de um gestor dessa companhia com `X1 = 39` anos de idade e `X2 = 4` anos de faculdade, será só usar `predict`.

```
predict(modelo, newdata = data.frame(X1 = 39, X2 = 4))
#      1 
#83639.1
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que me pareceu nos comentários e pelo link que você postou, seu objetivo é fazer uma regressão linear adjunta de uma previsão. Aqui vai a solução:

**a)** análise

```
df <- data.frame(
  y = c(81.7, 73.3, 89.5, 79.8, 69.9), 
  x1 = c(38, 46, 39, 43, 32), 
  x2 = c(4, 0, 5, 2, 4)
)

reg <- lm(
  y ~ x1 + x2, data = df
)

summary(reg)

#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = df)

#Residuals:
#       1        2        3        4        5 
# 0.02182 -0.16295 -0.11476  0.26851 -0.01263 

#Coefficients:
#         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept) -16.73960    1.62926  -10.27 0.009341 ** 
#x1            1.96092    0.03529   55.56 0.000324 ***
#x2            5.97566    0.09388   63.65 0.000247 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

#Residual standard error: 0.2371 on 2 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.9995,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.999 
#F-statistic:  2074 on 2 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.0004819
```

**b)** previsão

```
forec <- data.frame(x1 = 39, x2 = 4)
predict(reg, newdata = forec, interval = 'confidence', level = .95)

#       fit      lwr      upr
# 1 83.6391 83.07115 84.20706
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: É  `x2 = 4`, não é `5`.